# Simple recursive CYPHER query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is an extremely simple question, but reading [through the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-introduction.html) for the first time, I can't figure out how to construct this query. Let's say I have a graph that looks like:

[image]

and additionally each person has an age associated with them. 
**What CYPHER query will get me a list of John's age and all the ages of the entire friend tree of John?**

What I've tried so far:

```
MATCH (start)-[:friend]>(others)
 WHERE start.name="John"
 RETURN start.age, others.age
```

This has several problems,

1. It only goes one one one friend deep and I'd like to go to *all* friends of John.
2. It doesn't return a list, but a series of `(john.age, other.age)`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So what you need is not only friend of john, but also friends of friends. So you need to tell neo4j to recursively go deep in the graph.

This query goes 2 level deep.

```
MATCH (john:Person { name:"John" })-[:friend *1..2]->(friend: Person)
RETURN friend.name, friend.age;
```

To go `n` nevel deep, don't put anything i.e. `*1..`

Oh and I also found this [nice example](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-friend-finding.html) in neo4j

So what does `*1..2` here means:

`*` to denote that its a recursion.

`1` to denote that do not include john itself i.e. is the start node. If you put 0 here, it will also include the `John node` itself.

`..` to denote that go from this node till ...

`2` denotes the level of recursion. Here you say to stop at level 2. i.e. dont go beyond steve. If you put nothing there, it will keep on going until it cannot find a node that "has" a friend relationship

**Documentation** for these types of query match is [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#relationships-in-depth) and a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718784/querying-recursive-relationship-chains-in-neo4j-with-cypher).

Comment: yes, that will take you all the way deep. So if steve had a friend x, and x had a friend y, all will come in.

Comment: Thanks for the example @Rash this will go a long way! I just figured out if I start at `0` instead of `1` I get the original node too.

Comment: @Hooked Thanks. but damn the documentation. I am trying to find the definitions but I cannot locate them. All i wrote is from what I remember.

Comment: @Hooked Hi. I have updated the answer with the documentation that I can find.

Comment: There is a nice explanation of recursion lengths here (including pictures): https://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html

Comment: How do you also return the "parent" columns, i.e. "who" has friend who.  For instance last row would have column values: Sara, Maria, Maria.age

Comment: Ok you would probably do something like for the Persons example in `:play cypher` this query `MATCH p = (a:Person { name:"Emil" })-[k:KNOWS *1..2]->(kn: Person)
RETURN nodes(p)[length(p)-1].name, length(p), kn.name, kn.from;`