# Cypher to return chain of self referencing relationship in a compact stringified format?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's assume I have a self referencing relationship:

```
(User)-[REPORTS_TO]->(User)
```

How can I write cypher such that for each user, I return a string for each user that denotes the reports to lineage for that user (of arbitrary depth in a management chain)? That is: if Joe reports to Jane, and Jane reports to John, for the MATCH on 'Joe', I would get as a string (delimiter is ',' here but can be whatever):

Joe , Jane , John

for Jane it would be:

Jane , John

and for John it would be:

John

(An alternative to this where one field would contain the target user and the other would contain the report to lineage is also welcomed)

Comment: So basically, you want to convert the list `[joe, jane, john]` to the string `"joe, jane, john"`?

Comment: I wouldn't mind the information being returned in a list format, but the difficulty I'm having is capturing the self referencing information into this format. Given the simplified schema above where as user self references user with this relationship, how can I capture the recursive relationship into a list for each target user via Cypher?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple recursive CYPHER query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079881/simple-recursive-cypher-query)

Comment: Yes, this cypher pattern I'm familiar with. However, each piece of information is returned in their own row relative to just one target user. I wanted to see if I could get the (in that case) friend tree compacted into one ordered list/string for each target user.

Comment: Just change the return to `RETURN start, COLLECT(others)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one, you can either return the collection of person names in the chain:

```
MATCH path = (person:User)-[:REPORTS_TO*]->(top)
WHERE NOT (top)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
RETURN person.name as name, [node in nodes(path) | node.name] as reportingChain
```

Or use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_functions) to join the name list elements into a string:

```
MATCH path = (person:User)-[:REPORTS_TO*]->(top)
WHERE NOT (top)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
WITH person.name as name, [node in nodes(path) | node.name] as reportingChain
RETURN name, apoc.text.join(reportingChain, ',') as reportingChainText
```